# Android set padding for hint text

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to set the padding for the hint inside an EditText in Android?

Cannot seem to find any documentation in regards.

Comment: just add `android:paddingStart="xxx"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
 <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:hint="Hint Text"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add padding to hint text only. but you can apply padding for both hint and text using `paddingStart` attribute.

```xml
android:paddingStart="16dp"
```